# Actual code appears when running instead of PHP

Tags: php, text

I have been studying from a book but there are a few pieces in the book that do not seem to work when I open them in a browser but work on online php editors. Can you guys help me rectify the code?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>listing 12-9</title>
</head>enter code here
<body>
<?php
    $Today = date("l F d, Y");
    print ("Today is $Today, I will check your diary...<br>\n");

    $diaryDate = date("d");

    if ($diaryDate==3) print ("you have a dinner date");
    else
    if ($diaryDate==10) print ("dentist appointment today");
    else
    if ($diaryDate==23) print ("have the day off!");
    else
    if ($diaryDate==29) print ("go to conference");
    else
    print ("You have no booked events today!");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and also:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>listing 12-8</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $Today = date ("l F d, Y");
        print ("Today is $Today, I will check your diary...<br>\n");

        $diaryDate = date ("d");

        switch($diaryDate)
        {
            case 3: print("you have a dinner date"); break;
            case 10: print("dentist appointment today"); break;
            case 23 : print("have the day off!"); break;
            case 29: print ("go to conference"); break;
            default: print("You have no booked events today!");
            }

    ?>
    </body></html>
```

Thanks

Comment: What filenames are you using? Have you given them the .php extension? Are you running them through a webserver, or just opening the files directly in your browser?

Comment: The file names are list12-9 and list-12-8. The previous ones using list12-6 have worked. Both have html extentions and I'm using xampp and using localhost to open the files

Comment: They must have the .php extension, even if they are mostly HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a local web server to execute the PHP in the browser on your local machine.  PHP code is processed by a server and rendered for the browser, so without a webserver running PHP on your local machine it will not render.

Look into installing [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (for windows) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (for Mac).

The files also require the `.php` extension, even if they are mostly HTML content.

Comment: Most Windows PCs come with IIS or IIS can be installed for free, on which you can run PHP. It's called a WIMP stack when installed with MySQL (Windows + IIS + MySQL + PHP).

Comment: @Jasper thats too complex, I personaly prefer XAMPP

Comment: Ah, tyvm. I do have a Apache via xampp working. The book does not specify the file type, so it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: @meda Just a suggestion. Why is it too complex though? You can get a web server up and running with installers and not having to do any manual configuration.

Comment: @Ennui , +1  from me just in case you don't hear from OP he he

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I don't have 15 reputation! When I do, I'll make sure to come back to this.